# How to use calendar with event in xamarin cross platform

Tags: c#, xamarin, calendar, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

How to use calendar with show event option when select any date  in xamarin cross platform

Comment: You should read this before asking questions in order to receive more help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Good question, however not the best grammar or formatting, any recent answers here?  Looking for a Xamarin C# Cross-Platform Nuget Package that you can install to write code that will save Calendar Events (formerly .ics files) to the local device.  As far as I know you need to write native code to achieve this, however I have seen a couple of Nuget packages floating around, have not tested anything yet.

EDIT

Going to try these out.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CClarke.Plugin.Calendars/0.1.0-alpha

https://github.com/FrazzApps/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/CalendarConnector

EDIT

It looks like High Grand Wizard James Montemagno is recommending option #1
  C. Clarke's Calendars Plugin.  See his article here.

https://devhub.io/repos/jamesmontemagno-Calendars

Comment: What did you end up using?